# Is it possible to use opendns on centos 5 vps

Tags: vps, opendns

I have a centos 5 vps, didn't want to install any cpanel, i want to setup nameservers so is it possible to use opendns to do that and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I see nothing difficult. Install BIND and add something like that in the configuration file:

```
zone "." {
        type forward;
        forward first;
        forwarders {208.67.222.222; 208.67.220.220; 8.8.8.8; };
};
```

These IPs are os OpenDNS servers (last is Google's). This configuration works on my proxy server.

EDIT:
If you don't need DNS *server* on your machine, you may just add:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

to your /etc/resolv.conf file. Leave only them there or place them first if you have any other nameservers there.

Or I've missed some details?

Comment: thx sir i solved it